# Basic styling in Orchard CMS

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, orchardcms

I want to allow admin users of my CMS-driven sites change basic css properties, add a logo and change pre-determined text items without having any knowledge of HTML or CSS.

I may have missed something but I can't see an easy way of doing this in Orchard without creating custom themes.

The Orchard system will be multi-tenant, by sub-domain.

My architecture consists of a brochure-style website which i'm happy to allow full control to the user through Orchard and a transactional mvc 3 website which i'm implementing as an Orchard Module.  The user has much less control over the transactional website, but i would like them to be able to choose the background-colour, font attributes a logo and some text.

Does anyone know if this approach is supported by Orchard and if so, some examples would be nice!

I guess ideally i'd like for the admin user to set up the css values of the transactional site in the Orchard admin using colour-pickers for example.  If i could then pull these values out of the Orchard DB with Razor like:

```
background-color: @Html.GetCMSValue("backgroundCssColour")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what you are asking for: http://orchardproject.net/gallery/List/Themes/Orchard.Theme.SuperClassic

Comment: Hi Bertrand, thanks for the quick answer - was exactly what i was looking for!  It works fine when i install it through orchard themes gallery, but when i take the package you specify above and install it into the orchard src i get a nasty compilation error: The type 'SuperClassic.ViewModels.SettingsViewModel' exists in both '...Temporary ASP.NET Files\orchardlocal\833be1ed\a58fe112\assembly\dl3\ed089c8d\5c1dd973_4c95cc01\Orchard.Web.DLL' and '...Temporary ASP.NET Files\orchardlocal\833be1ed\a58fe112\App_Web_rzflsivc.dll'.  Any idea what i might have done wrong?

Comment: That can sometimes happen when you have both a compiled dll for the module and a more recent version of the source in two different places. I would find the asp.net temporary folder and wipe it clean. Then it should work fine.